# Databound Combobox not unfocusing

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I'm trying to make a databound combobox in a bindingnavigator. I want the options for the combobox to come from a different table and have a different display and value member.

So I have a member table and a group table and each member has a group determined by a fk_Group column. I want the combobox to be able to select from the currently existing options in the group table to set the member fk_Group to one of the pk_Groups that already exists.

So far I have the combobox properties set to
datasource: groupbindingsource
Display Member: GroupName
ValueMember: pk_Group
CausesValidation: False
Databinding SelectedValue: memberBindingSource - fk_Group

This makes sense to me and the combobox populates correctly but when I click an option I can't remove focus from it and the drop down starts behaving oddly, immediately snapping back up when it comes down.

I can get out of it by using the bindingnavigators arrows to go to a different record but then it clears the combobox.

Ideally I would like the combobox to populate with the current group name for that member as well as be able to select from a list of the other groups.

Thanks

Comment: This occurs if the value of data-bound field which you set using `SelectedValue` doesn't exist in values from `DataSource` of `ComboBox`. In this case, it means the value of `fk_Group` for a record, doesn't exist between `pk_Group`s of `groupbindingsource`.

Comment: What I want is for fk_group to be set by selecting from a list of pk_group. How would I do that without one of them being different?